# Is there any way to update JQGrid view automatically when underlying model is updated

Tags: javascript, jsp, jqgrid

```
**Is there any way to update JQGrid view automatically when underlying model is updated.**
```

i.e, if back-end data is updated in data base, is it possible to show
    updated data in JQGrid view without refresing the grid.

or, in similar way like MVVM architecture, when model gets updated, it will
    send a notification to view and view will be reloaded with updated data.

Comment: You formulate you question too unclear. Which MVVM product you use? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). How you use jqGrid (for example which `datatype` you use)? jqGrid can't guess that the data is updated. You can should inform jqGrid to refresh (repaint) the grid after the data are changes. You can either modify one row of data or reload the grid from new local data (JavaScript array) or from `url`

Comment: In my case I am using free JQGrid only. In my project some component will update database table continuously. Hence I question was, is there any way I can show updated view to user after database/table is updated by some other components. Or binding jqgrid data such  way that when ever underlying data is updated view will be notified, so that I can refresh the view. I have used MVVM term because I have used microsoft silverlight control with MVVM for similar kind of requirements in other porjects. @Oleg